# Sorting alphanumeric array numerically using QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, array

For each street I have a list of house numbers in a column of a CSV file and I need to sort them numerically:

House numbers are separated by `-`.

| name | list | sorted_list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| street A | 5/A-5-4-8-3-6-9-7-1-10-7/B-2-7/A | 1,2,3,4,5,5/A,6,7,7/A,7/B,8,9,10 |
| street B | 15-1-2/AX-2-3 | 1,2,2/AX,3,15 |

How can I get the `sorted_list` column?

I used this expression, but I find it complicated and slow;

```
array_to_string(
array_foreach(
    array_sort(
        with_variable('lista',
            string_to_array("sorted_list" ,'-'),
            array_foreach(generate_series(0, array_length(@lista)-1),
            lpad(regexp_substr( (@lista[@element]),'(\\d+)'),3,'0')
            ||'|'||
            if(regexp_substr((@lista[@element]),'([a-zA-Z/]+)') !='',
               regexp_substr((@lista[@element]),'([a-zA-Z/]+)'),
               ' ')
            ||'|'||
            @lista[@element]))),
regexp_replace( @element,'^.+\\|(.+)$','\\1'))
)
```

Is there an easier way to use expressions?

---

After a few days of study, my request is to obtain the [natural sorting](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/) as per Kadir's solution, but using the QGIS core expressions; but I think it is impossible and that the way through code is the only and fastest in terms of performance.

Here is a desired example:

| solution | value |
| --- | --- |
| list | 1-1/A-10-1r-2/10-10/1A2-10/A-1000/C1-SNC - to order |
| kadir | 1,1/A,1r,2/10,10,10/1A2,10/A,1000/C1,SNC |
| my | SNC,1,1r,1/A,2/10,10,10/1A2,10/A,1000/C1 |
| `sort -V` | 1,1r,1/A,2/10,10,10/1A2,10/A,1000/C1,SNC |
| `sort -n` | SNC,1,1/A,1r,2/10,10,10/1A2,10/A,1000/C1 |
| `natsort` | 1,1/A,1r,2/10,10,10/1A2,10/A,1000/C1,SNC |

`sort -V` and `sort -n` are the linux system solutions
[`natsort`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/) is python module and cli to run natural sort processing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a new function using Function Editor.

[image]

Copy/paste the following script:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import re

def natural_sort_key(s):
    ns = re.compile('([0-9]+)')
    return [int(t) if t.isdigit() else t.lower() for t in re.split(ns, s)]  

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesgeometry=False)
def sort_my_addresses(field, feature, parent):
    _list = feature[field].split("-")
    _list.sort(key=natural_sort_key)
     
    return ','.join(_list)
```

Click on "Save and Load Functions" button. Use this expression:

```
sort_my_addresses('list')
```

Note: the field parameter name (`list` here) for `sort_my_addresses` should be between single quotes (`'`), not double quotes (`"`). For example, `'field_name'`, not `"field_name"`.

[image]

Reference for `natural_sort_key` method: [How to sort a list containing alphanumeric values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19366686/5569709)

Comment: good solution, but I am looking for a simple solution through the use of QGIS core functions, THANK YOU

Answer (score 7):

Two approaches that resolve different parts of the problem and could maybe help finding an easier solution. Approach 3 solves the problem, based on approach 2, but is similarily complex as your initial expression.

### Approach 1: `array_prioritize`

Integer-only elements will be sorted correctly, combined alpha-numerical strings will be put at the end:

```
array_to_string (
    array_prioritize(
        string_to_array("list" ,'-'), 
        generate_series(1,1000)
    )
)
```

[image]

### Approach 2: using `map()` functions

Correct sorting of integer only and mixed alpha-numerical values, but only of the same length of the numerical part - so refining this to run separately for single-digit, two-digit and three-digit values should return the correct order:

```
array_to_string (
    array_prioritize(
        map_akeys(
            hstore_to_map( 
                array_to_string(
                    array_foreach (
                        string_to_array("list" ,'-'),
                        @element  ||  '=>'  ||  regexp_substr( @element, ('\\d+'))
                    )
                )
            )
        ), 
        array (1,1000)
    )
)
```

[image]

### Approach 3: running approach 2 separately for single/two digit values

Adapting approach 2 from above to take into consideration only single digit house numbers, this expression return the correct alpha-numerical sort order. Change `1` to `2` for two digit values (and so on) in line 10 and concatenate the resulting strings:

```
array_to_string (
    array_prioritize(
        map_akeys(
            hstore_to_map( 
                array_to_string(
                    array_foreach (
                        array_foreach (
                            string_to_array("list" ,'-'),
                            if (
                                length (regexp_substr( @element, ('\\d+'))) =1,  -- no. of digits
                                @element, ''
                            )
                        ),
                        @element  ||  '=>'  ||  regexp_substr( @element, ('\\d+'))
                    )
                )
            )
        ), 
        array (1,1000)
    )
)
```

To avoid repaeting the above expression for each length (no. o digits), again add an `array_for_each()` function. Line 3 defines the no. of digits for which the expression should run - here for 1- and 2-digit lengths:

```
array_to_string (
    array_foreach (
        array(1,2), -- no. of digits to take into consideration
        with_variable(
            'digits',
            @element,
            array_to_string (
                array_prioritize(
                    map_akeys(
                        hstore_to_map( 
                            array_to_string(
                                array_foreach (
                                    array_foreach (
                                        string_to_array("list" ,'-'),
                                        if (
                                            length (regexp_substr( @element, ('\\d+'))) = @digits,
                                            @element, ''
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    @element  ||  '=>'  ||  regexp_substr( @element, ('\\d+'))
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ), 
                    array (1,1000)
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

And, changing line 3 either to `array(1,2,3),` or to `generate_series(1,3,1),` three-digit values are also sorted correctly:
[image]

Comment: in case you use array (1,3) in line three, it would not consider the two-digit numbers :-(

Comment: You're right, once again! To include two-digit numbers, it must be either `array(1,2,3),` or `generate_series(1,3)`. I updated the solution accordingly.

Comment: I did a test with my data, my expression takes 125 seconds, yours double; I also notice that it adds a comma to the end or the beginning of the string. :-(

Comment: Yeah, not a real improvement... Thanks for the feedback. No easy solution available, it seems (no one that improves your expression).

Comment: thanks for your time :-)

Answer (score 5):

A slightly different approach to solving the problem from the solutions till now proposed is the following expression:

```
array_to_string(
    array_foreach(
        array_sort(
            array_foreach(
                string_to_array(
                    replace('5/A-5-16/B-4-18-15-22-3-14-12-6-16/A-16/FG-9-11-13-7-21-1-19-10-7/A-17-123-20','-',',')),
                lpad(@element,((max_length(regexp_substr(@element,'(\\d+)')))+3)+length(regexp_replace(@element,'\\d+','')),0)
            )   
        ),
    regexp_replace(regexp_replace(@element, '^00',''),'^0',''))
)
```

With this expression, both elements with one or more letters and numbers with more than two-digit are processed and ordered correctly.

[image]

Comment: I tried the expression with my dataset, my expression takes 125 seconds, yours after 10 minutes I stopped it, it seems too slow.Also it doesn't handle 5/1-5/A cases correctly, I know it's not in the example. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different approach, converting the characters to its ascii code and adding it as decimals to the house numbers, creating decimal numbers that are then sorted and afterwards coverted back to the initial format:

```
array_to_string (
    array_foreach (
        array_sort (
            array_foreach (
                string_to_array (list,'-'),
                to_real (
                    concat (
                        regexp_substr (
                            @element,   
                            ('\\d+')
                        ),  
                        '.' ,
                        ascii(
                            regexp_substr (
                                replace (@element, '/',''),
                                ('\\D+')
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        floor(@element)  || 
        if (@element > floor (@element), '/', '') || 
        char (100*round (@element -floor(@element),2))
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't handle house numbers with multiple letters, see `2/AX` which becomes just `2/A`  or `29/BAC` in` 29/B`

Comment: the problem is in the `ascii` and `char` functions which return the value of only one character

Comment: I see. This could be adressed somehow, but would make this rather complex expression even more complex. You have a working expression and are looking for an easier one, so that makes no sense.

Comment: I first tried `map` functions, creating key:value pairs like from 5/A -> `5:5/A` or inverse, then sort the keys or values (the numerical part) and get the corresponding values /keys (the whole alphabumerical string). But quite tricky, too. However, nice question, hope to see an easier expression.

Comment: it would be nice to have an optional parameter in the `array_sort` function to do natural sorting

Comment: A feature request? However, how should this option recognize the pattern/how to sort for any possible format? Your example is tricky enough.... I experimented with `array_prioritize`, maybe that could help, but not sure if the expression would get easier than yours.

Comment: If there is not in the core functions, it is the right time to make one. @Babel is right: "*your example is tricky enough*". I think the best option is to build a new function for your particular problem.

Comment: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/46850